# How to access varaible nested JSON data model in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, post

Here is my model class,

```
export class a{
ab: Ab;
b: string;
 }

 export class Ab{
var: string;
 }
```

Now I want to set the value for variable 'var' in class 'Ab', for that I am writing

```
cont a = new a();
a.ab.var = 'demo text';
```

If I work like this I get the following error,

```
Cannot set property 'var' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'var' of undefined
```

I also want to send this type pf more complex json data as POST request, so any way how to access this variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the 'a' class, the 'ab' variable takes a null value while creating the class. `ab: Ab` simply specifies the type of variable `ab`. If you create a new object `ab` in the constructor of the class `a`, the problem will be solved.

```
export class a {
    ab: Ab;
    b: string;
    constructor() {
        this.ab = new Ab();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot this worked, what if I have ab: Ab[] than what should I write in my contructor?

Comment: like this `this.ab = new Array<Ab>();`

Comment: than when I access in my ts file a.ab[0].var it again gives same error var is undefined

Comment: If `this.ab = new Array<Ab>();` after the code,`this.ab[0]` will give an error. After `this.ab = new Array<Ab>();`, you have to write the code `this.ab.push(new Ab());` and push the element into the list. In this way, there will be an `Ab` type element in the 1st index of the list you have.